# $\cos z=\cosh 2$ all solutions for z

Tags: complex-analysis

$\cos z = \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2}$, $\cosh 2 = \frac{e^{2} + e^{-2}}{2}$, $z = x + iy$

We can see that $e^{iz} = e^{2} \implies e^{ix -y} = e^{2} \implies e^{-y}(\cos x + i \sin x) = e^2$

So then obviously $y = -2$, $x = 0 + 2 \pi k$

Finally I get $z = 2 \pi k -2i$ but the book has $z = 2 \pi k \pm 2i$

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $u+\frac{1}{u} = v+\frac{1}{v}$ then $u=v$ or $u=\frac{1}{v}$.

You have $u=e^{iz}$ and $v=e^2$. You've only considered $u=v$.